# How to use URL parameters for webform

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views, url-parameters, drupal-webform

With webform I created a form with several pairs of components that belong to eachother. For example, a component "name" of type text field and a component "name" of type markup. The intention is that the submission of the text field will displayed in the Markup field.

Using Roles will be provided for the user which textareas should fill out and what markup fields he or she sees. In this way I want different users (students in this case) to communicate with a single user (a teacher). The text submitted by a student in a textarea will then be showed as read-only text for the teacher.

With the help of the unsurpassed Johan Falk, http://vimeo.com/18701843, can I get data from web form submission data into Views. By using the submission id (sid) on contextual filters I can select the submission of a specific student and display it. In the preview in Views this works fine.

Using contextual filters can I use with the submission ID of the input of a user (student) select. In the preview Views this works fine. Then I import the block into the markup field with the following php code:

```
<? php
   $ block = module_invoke ('views', 'block_view', 'block_delta');
  print render ($ block ['content']);
?>
```

Here begins my question!

The above `print render ($ block ['content']);` the block appears as a survey of the submissions of all users (students). However, I want use a url parameter to display a single submission of a specific user as in the preview in Views mentioned above. I have searched for a way to add a filter to this php code above but cant find a solution.

Does anyone have an idea how to tackle it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe you can generate the block you want with the given filters applied solely with Views.

1. Try creating a new view of type **Webform submissions**. (/admin/build/views/add)
2. Add a Block display
3. Add the relationship **Webform submissions: User** and make sure it is required.
4. Add the filter **User: Current Yes** and it should be using your relationship (Webform Submission User).

This should filter the block output to submissions from the currently logged in user.

Comment: Your answer is near but not quite right.
I use a form to teach students a report should be prepared. A field for the title, a textarea for the intro, and so on. The teacher has a table with the names of the students and if a name is clicked it sees the subm. of the student (detail page). Then the teacher under each item of the subm. (title, intro, and so on) comments. This is then the student text to read.
Your solution works with a student, but not with the teacher the work of several students to assess. Since the subm. of each student has their own sid it is my idea to filter on this sid.